# How .transform handle the splitted groups?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 'level': ['hard', None, None, 'easy', None, 'medium']})

print(df)

  subject   level
0       a    hard
1       a    None
2       b    None
3       b    easy
4       c    None
5       d  medium
```

When using the code :

```
df.groupby('subject').transform(lambda group: print(group))
```

I got four printed groups. That's ok because we have four subjects : `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`
But I don't understand the group 2, i feel like transform have accumulated the values of the two first groups. Also, there is a weird indentation that seem to separate the first group from the second one

```
# ------------------------ group1
0    hard
1    None
Name: level, dtype: object
# ------------------------ group2
  level
0  hard
1  None
2    None
3    easy
Name: level, dtype: object
# ------------------------ group3
4    None
Name: level, dtype: object
# ------------------------ group4
5    medium
Name: level, dtype: object
```

Can someone please explain the logic to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not, but [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) runs some checks to see the type of the output. In general you don't use `transform` for its side effects (you should use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) as shown later), but rather to return something of the same shape as the input.

What exactly happens might be more explicit with a custom function:

```
def f(group):
    print('---')
    print(group.name)  # with `transform` this shouldn't give the group name
    print(group)
    print('===')
    
df.groupby('subject').transform(f)
```

Output:

```
---                           # first group
level
0    hard
1    None
Name: level, dtype: object
===
---                           # internal pandas check (not a real group)
a
  level
0  hard
1  None
===
---                           # second group
level
2    None
3    easy
Name: level, dtype: object
===
---                           # third group
level
4    None
Name: level, dtype: object
===
---                           # fourth group
level
5    medium
Name: level, dtype: object
===
```

In comparison, using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) that does give the group names and which you can use for this kind of operations:

```
df.groupby('subject').apply(f)

---
a
  subject level
0       a  hard
1       a  None
===
---
b
  subject level
2       b  None
3       b  easy
===
---
c
  subject level
4       c  None
===
---
d
  subject   level
5       d  medium
===
```

##### don't use `transform` to manually work on groups.

Here is another example. In `transform`, `group.name` returns the current `Series` name, see what happens with multiple columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'level': ['hard', None, None, 'easy', None, 'medium'],
                   'level2': ['hard', None, None, 'easy', None, 'medium']
                  })
df.groupby('subject').transform(lambda g: print(g.name))
```

`print` output:

```
level    # first group, column "level"
level2   # first group, column "level2"
a        # some internal check run only once
level    # second group, column "level"
level2   # second group, column "level2"
level    # etc.
level2
level
level2
```

In comparison, `apply` would return each group as DataFrame:

```
df.groupby('subject').apply(lambda g: print(g.name))

a
b
c
d
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. The indentation was confusing me because there is a concatenation between two consecutive runs if I understand it good. But to be honest, I still can't understand the "# internal pandas check (not a real group)". Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: I don't understand how but when I do `df.groupby('subject')['level'].transform(f)`, the check run is gone.

Comment: I added another example. In short, you should not worry about that, it's an internal check and it might change in the future. You should never see it because you should not use `transform` to loop over groups. Use `apply` for that.