# Groupby returns Series, then DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

Please consider this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1, 1, 2, 2], 
                   "b" : [1, 1, 2, 3], 
                   "s1": [1, np.nan,3, np.nan], 
                   "s2": [np.nan,2, 3, np.nan]})
print(df)

def compute(g):
    print(type(g))
    print(g)
    return g
df.groupby(["a", "b"]).transform(lambda g: compute(g))
```

Basically, I want group df using two columns, then apply a function to each group, that needs to be a dataframe with columns "s1" and "s2".

The output of the previous code is:

```
   a  b   s1   s2
0  1  1  1.0  NaN
1  1  1  NaN  2.0
2  2  2  3.0  3.0
3  2  3  NaN  NaN
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    1.0
1    NaN
Name: s1, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    NaN
1    2.0
Name: s2, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    s1   s2
0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  2.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    s1   s2
2  3.0  3.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
   s1  s2
3 NaN NaN
```

As you can see, in the first two iterations the function receives a pd.Series, specifically, it receives "s1", then "s2", then the three dataframes.

I cannot understand why the function received the two columns separately at the beginning of the iteration.

Comment: What happens if you write instead: `for g in df.groupby(["a","b"]): compute(g)`
Also I don't quite understand what the transform operation should achieve.

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77300078/how-transform-handle-the-splitted-groups), `transform` is not designed to use custom functions in a loop (or functions with side-effects). use `apply`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion arises from the behavior of the transform function when applied to grouped data. Here's a breakdown of what's happening:

When you use the transform method with a grouped object, the function you provide as an argument is applied to each column of each group. This is the default behavior of transform. So, when you group by a and b, the function compute gets applied to each column of the group, hence the initial iterations with Series inputs.

To avoid this and operate on the dataframe directly, one option is to use the apply method instead of transform. The apply method applies the function to the entire group at once, preserving the dataframe structure.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a" : [1, 1, 2, 2], 
    "b" : [1, 1, 2, 3], 
    "s1": [1, np.nan, 3, np.nan], 
    "s2": [np.nan, 2, 3, np.nan]
})

def compute(g):
    print(type(g))
    print(g)
    return g

# Group and apply the function
result = df.groupby(["a", "b"]).apply(compute)
print(result)
```

Using apply will ensure that compute receives a dataframe for each group, not individual series for each column of each group.

Comment: That is how ended up implementing it, but I could not understand the behaviour from the documentation of pandas. Where could I read something more?

Comment: the question is, why did you want to implement it with `transform`?